# Autoanswer: Conventional wisdom seems incorrect

Tags: android, headset

I have been working on a means of automatically answering a phone call using the "KeyEvent" method that so many people seem to swear by.

This method works on a simulator but *does not work* onb an actual device.

The code I am using is provided below:

```
  Intent buttonDown = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
  buttonDown.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
  ctx.sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonDown, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");

  Intent buttonUp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
  buttonUp.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
  ctx.sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonUp, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");

  Intent headSetUnPluggedintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);
  headSetUnPluggedintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY);
  headSetUnPluggedintent.putExtra("state", 1); // 0 = unplugged  1 = Headset with microphone 2 = Headset without microphone
  headSetUnPluggedintent.putExtra("name", "Headset");
  // TODO: Should we require a permission?
  ctx.sendOrderedBroadcast(headSetUnPluggedintent, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
```

What happens is that on a simulator the answer "button" appears to work. Unfortunately, on an actual phone it looks like the KeyEvent that is being sent is being completely ignored.

Has anyone found a reliable way to perform this action on Android 2.3.*?

Answer (score 0):

you 're sending the fake headset connection event after the headset button event. how can a headset that is not connected yet answer the call? first connect the fake headset and then send the fake button press. it works for me.